# Make a record combining its duplicate records based combination of two columns and assign the Min start_date and Max end_date

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands, db2-luw

This image will show you the problem structure

[image: 1]

This should be the desired output

[image: 2]

I want to populate the **Min** *Start_Date* and **Max** *End_Date* from the duplicate record (duplicate based on *Present* and *Absent* column) of that record and make a master record, same with other combination of *Present* and *Absent* column.

I have done order by on id and start date, to understand behavior of data.
this scenario I have mentioned for only one ID, the other IDs present should also give same kind of output, I can implement the correct logic on whole table if I get a working solution for this example.
I have tried using window function yet not achieved any solution.
Thanks in advance

**Note the number of duplicate records of an **ID** based on present and absent column are variable.**

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: Are you using Oracle or DB2?

Comment: Thanks for your time. as i am learning stack culture, so my apologies for that.

Comment: yes i am using oracle, but same i have to implement in db2.

Comment: What happened to row 5?  It just disappeared from the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. Consider using the difference between row numbers to build groups of "adjacent" records, that you can then merge:

```
select id, min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date end_date, present, absent
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by start_date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by id, present, absent order by start_date) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by id, present, absent, rn1 - rn2
order by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
   PARTITION BY id
   ORDER BY     start_date
   MEASURES     FIRST( start_date ) AS start_date,
                MAX( end_date )     AS end_date,
                FIRST( present )    AS present,
                FIRST( absent )     AS absent
   ONE ROW PER MATCH
   PATTERN      (FIRST_ROW EQUAL_ROWS*)
   DEFINE       EQUAL_ROWS AS
   (
     (
       (
         EQUAL_ROWS.present = PREV(EQUAL_ROWS.present)
       ) OR (
         EQUAL_ROWS.present IS NULL AND PREV(EQUAL_ROWS.present) IS NULL
       )
     ) AND (
       (
         EQUAL_ROWS.absent  = PREV(EQUAL_ROWS.absent)
       ) OR (
         EQUAL_ROWS.absent IS NULL AND PREV(EQUAL_ROWS.absent) IS NULL
       )
     )
   )
)
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, start_date, end_date, present, absent ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-02-01', DATE '2020-03-01', 'Y',  'N'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-03-04', DATE '2020-04-19', 'Y',  'N'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-03-06', DATE '2020-03-09', 'N',  'N'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-05-04', DATE '2020-09-04', 'N',  'Y'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-05-06', DATE '2020-06-26', 'N',  'Y'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-07-12', DATE '2020-08-12', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-08-13', DATE '2020-08-12', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ID | START_DATE | END_DATE  | PRESENT | ABSENT
> -: | :--------- | :-------- | :------ | :-----
>  1 | 01-FEB-20  | 19-APR-20 | Y       | N     
>  1 | 06-MAR-20  | 09-MAR-20 | N       | N     
>  1 | 04-MAY-20  | 04-SEP-20 | N       | Y     
>  1 | 12-JUL-20  | 12-AUG-20 | null    | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=815c897cd7847204b23e73953e310b06)*